# Can't Receive Data from RoboClaw Encoders While Using Python Code In Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, encoder, motordriver

We are working on a project that uses 2x15A Roboclaw Motor drivers. We are trying to extract the encoder value from roboclaw while using a Raspberry Pi 3.

The python code always prints the values of encoders as [0, 0] whatever we try. Rewiring also didn't work. We are able to see data when using basicmicro motion studio tool to access the roboclaw product directly from a computer. But we can not get a reading while using python code and Roboclaw library. Python code we use is from basicmicro's "Using RoboClaw Encoders" tutorial. We are also not receiving any errors in python, the code is able to utilize the motors with the same python code but not capable getting any data feedback from the encoders, all the returned values from the encoders are (0,0). Example of the code can be seen Below:

```
from roboclaw import Roboclaw
from time import sleep

roboclaw = Roboclaw("/dev/ttyS0", 38400)
roboclaw.Open()


motor_1_count = roboclaw.ReadEncM1(0x80)
print "Original:"
print motor_1_count

sleep(2)

roboclaw.SetEncM1(0x80, 10000)
motor_1_count = roboclaw.ReadEncM1(0x80)
print "After setting count:"
print motor_1_count

sleep(2)

roboclaw.ResetEncoders(0x80)
motor_1_count = roboclaw.ReadEncM1(0x80)
print "After resetting:"
print motor_1_count

sleep(2)

roboclaw.SpeedAccelDeccelPositionM1(0x80,10000,2000,10000,15000,1)
```

Comment: Is it really connected to the console port? If so, have you disabled the serial console connection?

Comment: i am unable to access the device for a short time , will reply back when i get the information

Comment: I have confirmed that the device is connected to the concole port and the serial console connection is enabled. So the problem seems to be different

Comment: If the console port is enabled and the device is connected to it, then that is the problem. You have a getty attached to it. The device should therefore be busy. Have you checked for the return code on the Open?